# Tags [angle] [angles]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Tags [angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angle) and [angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angles) are similar. Should be they merged?

Comment: The plural should become a synonym of the singular, let me have a look, might be proposed and just languishing (we really need more visibility on proposed synonyms folks can vote on)

Comment: Yes, the current synonyms workflow is almost unusable which is a shame.

Comment: @TimPost Having the plural as the main tag would make more sense to me. And there's no way at all for anyone to propose that, due to the use count difference. Also, to the downvoters (hoping that one sees my comment): why? I don't see any difference in the meaning of these tags.

Comment: Are we mathematicians that needs a "angles" tag? I think rather than retagging removing the tag is more appropriated (is not a programing language nor a well established function going for the tag wiki).

Comment: 'Angle' and 'angles' could be syntax, classes, libraries, namespaces, etc... for several programming languages, especially math biased ones.